# Querying Google Cloud datastore with ancestor not returning anything

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the [google cloud datastore library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/usage.html) a flexible environment on Google App Engine.

I have a `run` entity which I use as a parent for `pathway` entities:

```
ds = datastore.Client('project-name')
parent = ds.query(kind='run', order=('-timestamp',)).fetch(1)
parent = list(parent)[0]

print(parent.key)    # <Key('run', 1), project=project-name>
```

If I fetch some `pathway` entities, they seem to have the correct parent

```
pathways = ds.query(kind='pathway', order=('-timestamp',)).fetch(limit=10)

for pathway in pathways:
    print(pathway.key.parent)    # <Key('run', 1), project=project-name>
```

But if I try to filter with the parent like this:

```
pathways = ds.query(kind='pathway', ancestor=parent.key, order=('-timestamp',)).fetch(limit=10)
```

Then I get an error:

```
google.api.core.exceptions.PreconditionFailed
google.api.core.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: 412 no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: pathway
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
- name: timestamp
    direction: desc
```

How do I correctly filter with the parent entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to satisfy certain queries Cloud Datastore needs to build indexes.  The details are defined here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes

Defining the suggested index should make the query in question work.

Comment: Ah thanks! It seems I completed missed the bit about indexes.